# How to calculate averages when some rows are missing on PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

Considering this dataset:

```
Day        | City      | Sales
2019-01-20 | London    | 900
2019-01-20 | Paris     | 800
2019-01-20 | Sao Paulo | 700
2019-01-21 | London    | 700
2019-01-21 | Paris     | 800
```

I need to calculate the sales average by day, for each city. But, there is no record for Sao Paulo on 2019-01-21. It should be understood as zero, with no sales.

When I create a simple average, PowerBI ignores the missing record and divides the total (700 + 800) by two (London and Paris).

How can I calculate the average by day, including the missing records (Sao Paulo)?

---

**SOLUTION**

I have found a solution. I don't think it's the best way to solve it, but it worked.

So...

1. Create a calendar table with monthly interval

```
MonthCalendar = 
var FullCalendar = ADDCOLUMNS(CALENDAR("2019-1-1";DATE(YEAR(NOW());MONTH(NOW())+1;DAY(NOW())));"Mês";EOMONTH([Date];0))
return 
SUMMARIZE(FullCalendar;[Mês])
```

2. Create a summarized table with the categories (in this case, the cities)
3. Create a CROSSJOIN table

```
DataTable = CROSSJOIN(MonthCalendar ; Cities)
```

4. Add columns to your DataTable using filters. Something like this:

```
SalesByMonth = CALCULATE(Sum('Cities'[Sales]); FILTER('Cities';'Cities'[name] = 'DataTable'[City]))
```

Thanks everybody. I hope it helps someone, someday.
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Instead of simply using the average function, you can use the following formula:

```
Sum(Sales)/ (Max(date) - Min(date))
```

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do here would be to add a row in your table with zero sales from the source (alternatively in the query). If you complete your data you will save yourself a lot of time if you want to do more analysis.

```
    Day    | City      | Sales
2019-01-20 | London    | 900
2019-01-20 | Paris     | 800
2019-01-20 | Sao Paulo | 700
2019-01-21 | London    | 700
2019-01-21 | Paris     | 800
2019-01-21 | Sao Paulo |   0
```

Because you (normally) never know what is the max citiys you get per day. But if the amount of citiys is fix you can use it hardcoded:

```
Measure = Sum(YourTable[Sales]) / 3
```

Now add a table visual and use the Measure and the Date and you will get your average per day.

[image]

Comment: I do not believe this is helping, think about the situation that there are two gaps, then we need to fill in 4?

Answer (score 0):

The real question is: Where do you want to take the average of? Power-bi is doing this based on the rows. this is logic.

Because you are working with dates, you want the average over a period, but what is the period you want to have the average of? a Week, the daydiff between the min and max? 3 days as in your example?

You can make the following MEASURE to solve your scenario but it still has the question: Where do you want the average of?

```
AverSales = 
var daysCount = CALCULATE(DATEDIFF(MIN(Sales[Date]);MAX(Sales[Date]);DAY);All(Sales))
return Sum(Sales[Sales])/daysCount
```

The daysCount is over the whole table, the min & max.